# how to make 3D DIV

Tags: html, css, 3d

How to make from regular rectangle DIV  a 3d rectangle like in the attached image?
[image]

The div can be 2 colors:

[image]

Comment: AFAIK you can't make a single div 3D like that, you'll need 7 divs, one to contain the box and 6 to make it. Hold on and I'll try to make an example.

Comment: I think you will have more sucess using the Canvas-element for this.

Comment: That looks like a bar chart from Excel. Are you trying to make a bar chart?

Comment: something like this but using divs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this (this example is for a cube):

HTML:

```
<div class="face top"></div>
<div class="face left"></div>
<div class="face right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.face{
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}

.top{
    background:#09f;
    border: 1px solid;
    top: 0px;
    left: 89px; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);  
}

.left{
    border: 1px solid;
    top: 155px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #09f;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);       
}

.right{
    border: 1px solid;
    top: 155px;
    left: 178px;
    background: #09f;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, -15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, -15deg);    
}
```

From: [image] to [image]

[Source](http://cssatoms.com/miscellaneous/create-a-3d-cube-in-pure-css3/)

[More on transformations](http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms)

Comment: hi:) i just posted the second image -it can be 2 colors - how can i do 2 colors?

Comment: Okay so that's ISO perspective.. how about 3 point :) Nice technique :)

Comment: @Sveta26 you might try background-image instead of background-color, but in that case, a simple image in the background div would be better. Consider not all browsers support css3 yet

Comment: @Scott webkit-perspective :D check this out:http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/ 3 point and all the perspectives in animation (some jquery to make it move). See here: http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/examples/perspective-01.html

Comment: Nope still top down iso :) Guess CSS3 can't do everything :) Thanks for sharing.

Comment: you could do it with canvas. Or you could construct the 3point with lots of triangles and other shapes. But you are right, challenge withdrawn, you can't with just css3 :(

Comment: Is it possiable to put background image instead of the div's border?

Comment: you can put the image inside the div (it will adjust it automatically)

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of being late and a tad repetitive,  Check out this http://www.useragentman.com/tests/cssSandpaper/cube3.html (Incase you want to support IE too!).

This being the actual formula generator for IE matrix transforms : http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/